# How can I access phone number in android with q python?

Tags: android, phone-call, qpython, qpython3

I try to access all phone number that calling me in Q python.

I wrote this code:

```
import androidhelper
w=1
while (w == 1):
   droid = androidhelper.Android()
   droid.startTrackingPhoneState()
   phonest = droid.readPhoneState()
   number = phonest[2] 
   if number != None:
       print(number)
```

I have not find any result when other call me or I call other
my device is lg k 10 2 sim.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Read this and look for exactly the command you need

https://www.qpython.org/en/guide_androidhelpers.html

Once you've found said command add

```
.result
```

To the end of it so only the result is returned

Comment: This doen't provide an answer to the question.

Comment: Muldec just add .result to the readphonestate command you used

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead and you'll get a result. As for getting the exact number I'm not so sure.

```
import androidhelper
w=1
while (w == 1):
   droid = androidhelper.Android()
   droid.startTrackingPhoneState()
   phonest = droid.readPhoneState().result
   number = phonest[2] 
   if number != None:
       print(number)
```